# Understanding RobotFramework Variables

Tags: python, robotframework

So I get that Robot has 3 types of variable 
Scalar which are like `${}`, List Which are like `@{}` and Dictionary which are like `&{}` but I dont understand it completely how they get treated in framework.
Like I created dictionary variable like

```
*** Variables ***
&{D}           A=a  'B'=b
```

And then can use it like

```
${new_D}=   Copy Dictionary ${D} 
${var}= Get From Dictionary ${New D}    MGMT_IP
```

Since D and new_D are of dictionary type why they should not always be prefixed by `&`. Same goes for list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&` prefix is used when creating the dictionary variable. Then you want to use the dict variable:

- if you use `$` prefix, then you access the dict as a whole. This is the most common way to use it, just like you do in your example.
- if you use the `&`prefix, then you get the individual items of the dictionary (list of key:value).

This is best understood with an example ([see the doc](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dictionary-variables)):

Assuming that a variable `&{USER}` has value `{'name': 'robot',    'password': 'secret'}`, the following two test cases are equivalent.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Constants
    Login    name=robot    password=secret

Dict Variable
    Login    &{USER}
```

But if you want to `Copy Dictionary` or `Log` the dict, then you access it with `${USER}`